# Make appear a text by cliking on a Vega lite Chart

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

_HI, I would like to make a text appear in a card when i click on a bar of my Dumbell Deneb Chart.
I tried but i didn't manage. Is it possible ? if not, il there a workaround ?
Thanks in advance.

[Pbix file here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8GTTVh81EyUlqJhF?e=GbDYos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a card and the same measure you use in the Deneb chart. e.g.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I don't know how come id didn't work for me... Thanks a lot !